# Magic Eden API instructions/buy_now

Tags: python, magiceden, solana-py

I'm trying to use Magic Eden API and solana-py to buy an NFT for the listed price. I'm using the `instructins/buy_now` endpoint to do that. I get an error when trying to buy the NFT. Have been trying to fix that for a few weeks, and I still can't. The part of the code for signing the TX:

```
account_sign = Keypair.from_secret_key(b58decode("xxxxxx"))
tx_signed = data['txSigned']
txn = Transaction.deserialize(bytes(tx_signed['data']))
txn.sign(account_sign)
await solana_client.send_raw_transaction(txn.serialize())
```

My error:

```
sign error: {'code': -32002, 'message': 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x7d3', 'data': {'accounts': None, 'err': {'InstructionError': [2, {'Custom': 2003}]}, 'logs': ['Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K invoke [1]', 'Program log: Instruction: Deposit', 'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]', 'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K consumed 9465 of 600000 compute units', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K success', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K invoke [1]', 'Program log: Instruction: Buy', 'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]', 'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success', 'Program log: {"price":32000000,"buyer_expiry":0}', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K consumed 26365 of 590535 compute units','Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K success', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K invoke [1]', 'Program log: Instruction: ExecuteSale', 'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. Error Code: ConstraintRaw. Error Number: 2003. Error Message: A raw constraint was violated.', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K consumed 23877 of 564170 compute units', 'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K failed: custom program error: 0x7d3'], 'unitsConsumed': 35830}}
```

The URL I'm sending to the ME API:

```
https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/instructions/buy_now?buyer=ADsE28NEc1hD9ZjocLBGrwARCuK5NTSi7HtwUktNbXD1&seller=D2AxugHdccsxy9KD7sUmZjJnvdgadYw4kptwDKaQPyQ&auctionHouseAddress=E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe&tokenMint=DefXNy9qma1CgEjFRbbaPjPdFAS1VuEwTY1Lt631zHqC&tokenATA=8LeRMLpcNbvewqNUs22yeP8cNvzod3C5ictURqT722Yj&price=0.01&sellerReferral=autMW8SgBkVYeBgqYiTuJZnkvDZMVU2MHJh9Jh7CSQ2&sellerExpiry=0
```

ME responds with something similar to this:

```
{
    "tx":
    {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data":
        [
            2,
            1,
            9,
            .....
        ]
    },
    "txSigned":
    {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data":
        [
            2,
            0,
            0,
            .....
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Really  need your help.

Comment: Have you tried another listing?

Comment: @Arowana I was checking on 2 collections and have been having the same issue. I tried another one right now and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation:
https://api.magiceden.dev/#51aff214-f517-47f6-b27b-66ca49029dbd

First you need to make sure you have an API key as the buy now request requires a bearer token.

Then our working instruction set is:

```
/instructions/buy-now
buyer=9X2******W35
seller=8dB******QtjZ
tokenMint=H9i******aq1L
tokenATA=7VW******Whg
price=3.5
auctionHouseAddress=E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe
sellerExpiry:-1
```

Edit:

The sellerExpiry is incorrect and will return a bad instruction set as I was saying.
I just purchased the example NFT using my example instruction set with the correct dynamic parameters filled in.
[image]

Comment: He mentioned he did get a response so of course he has an API key, it is the transaction itself that is failing.

Comment: yeah, I have the API key and the params are correct. I don't think that the order of the params is meaningful.

Comment: @Maxisy The params are not correct. I just purchased your example NFT using the reference instruction set posted. Your sellerExpiry is wrong.

Comment: @Arowana Documentation and authorization is good general information. Also the transaction data is incorrect, for good reason.

Comment: @BryonM what did you set the sellerExpiry to?

Comment: @Maxisy Mate read the docs or my comment, the params are literally right there. -1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the actual centralized app listing https://magiceden.io/item-details/DefXNy9qma1CgEjFRbbaPjPdFAS1VuEwTY1Lt631zHqC, the seller, tokenAta, auction house and price you have provided are correct.

During the execute_sale instruction it gives:

"Program log: AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. Error Code: ConstraintRaw. Error Number: 2003. Error Message: A raw constraint was violated."

So it is failing this constraint

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/auction-house/program/src/execute_sale/mod.rs#L124-L138

It doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong and this must be a bug on ME side or in the auction house code.

Comment: I think you need a Api key from magiceden to buy something. I’m not a experienced dev but this could be the problem right?

Comment: I do have the API key

Comment: It looks like it's a problem on ME's side, since my code worked well on another collection.

Comment: Ah then okay sorry

Comment: It is not an issue with ME. It is the parameters.